# 29 Differential equations hang/not solved in version 11 compared to 10.4, looking for cause

Tags: differential-equations

I run `Kamke` differential equations in version 11 and compared the result to version 10.4. Found `29` differential equations that are no longer solved in version 11. Actually `v11` hangs on these, eating more and more RAM with 100% cpu. At least I waited too long to find if it will finish. in `v10.4` each one is solved in less than 5 minutes.

With `10.4`, Mathematica solved `75.93%` of the problems, with version `11`, it solved `74.43%`.  So the performance went down.

There are `1940` differential equations. When I looked at the ones not solved in `v11`, I noticed in `10.4` the solution for them all has `Solve` in it. So the solution was implicit. Which is OK.  I thought may be Mathematica no longer return implicit solutions to an ODE. But I see other ODE's that are solved in `v11` that do have implicit solution. So this can't be the reason.

I am posting the ODE's here, to ask if someone can shed some light on why `v11` no longer solves these ODE's. May be there is some common reason for this. This looks like regression to me.

First I list the ODE's numbers. These are the ones not solved in `v11` but solved in `10.4`. When I say not solved, I mean it hanged. It did not actually return the input as normally would happen when it can't solve an ODE.

```
 {45, 52, 54, 58, 69, 70, 71, 185, 189, 204, 231, 249, 272, 338, 
  430, 459, 495, 501, 554, 571, 608, 622, 796, 815, 971, 983, 984, 
  1602, 1688}
```

Here are the 29 ODE's

```
 DSolve[3*b*y[x]^2 + 2*(-(b^2*x) + a^2*x^3)*y[x]^3 + y'[x] == 0, y[x], x]

 DSolve[-(b*x^(n/(1 - n))) - a*y[x]^n + Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[-((y[x]*Derivative[1][f][x])/f[x]) - f[x]*Derivative[1][g][x]
  - a^n*f[x]^(1 - n)*y[x]^n*Derivative[1][g][x] + 
  Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[-(b*x) - a*Sqrt[y[x]] + Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[-Sqrt[(a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4)*(b0 + b1*y[x] +
  b2*y[x]^2 + b3*y[x]^3 + b4*y[x]^4)] + Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[-Sqrt[(a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4)/(b0 + b1*y[x] + 
  b2*y[x]^2 + b3*y[x]^3 + b4*y[x]^4)] + Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[-Sqrt[(b0 + b1*y[x] + b2*y[x]^2 + b3*y[x]^3 + b4*y[x]^4)/(a0 
  + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4)] + Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[5*x^3*y[x]^2 + 2*(1 + x^2)*y[x]^3 + x^7*Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[-(b*x^((1 + m)*n)) - a*y[x]^n + x^(m*(-1 + n) + n)*
     Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[x + a*y[x] + y[x]*Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[EulerGamma + beta*x + alpha*y[x] + (c + b*x + a*y[x])*
     Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[beta*y[x]^2 + alpha*y[x]^3 + (b*x^n + a*x*y[x])*
     Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[-y[x]^2 + (x^2 + y[x]^2)*Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[2*x*Sin[alpha]*y[x] + Cos[alpha]*(-x^2 + y[x]^2) + x*
   Sqrt[x^2 + y[x]^2] + (-2*x*Cos[alpha]*y[x] + Sin[alpha]*
   (-x^2 + y[x]^2) + y[x]*Sqrt[x^2 + y[x]^2])*
   Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

DSolve[c0 + a0*x + b0*y[x] + (c1 + a1*x + b1*y[x])*
  Derivative[1][y][x] + (c2 + a2*x)*Derivative[1][y][x]^2 == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[E^(-2*y[x]) - (-1 + Derivative[1][y][x])^2 + 
   Derivative[1][y][x]^2/E^(2*x) == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[x^2 + (1 - a)*y[x]^2 + 2*a*x*y[x]*Derivative[1][y][x] + 
   ((1 - a)*x^2 + y[x]^2)*Derivative[1][y][x]^2 == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[d*y[x]^2 - b*y[x]*Derivative[1][y][x] + (c + b*x + 
    a*y[x]^2)*Derivative[1][y][x]^2 == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[y[x] - n*x*Derivative[1][y][x] + x^(-1 + n)*
      Derivative[1][y][x]^n == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[a*x^n*f[Derivative[1][y][x]] - y[x] + x*Derivative[1][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[Derivative[1][y][x] == Sqrt[y[x]]/(F[(x - y[x])/Sqrt[y[x]]] +
      Sqrt[y[x]]),y[x],x]

 DSolve[Derivative[1][y][x] == (2 + Sqrt[1 + 3*x] + y[x])^(-1),y[x],x]

 DSolve[Derivative[1][y][x] == (x*y[x]^3)/(3*E^((3*x^2)/2)*
     (3*E^((3*x^2)/2) + 3*y[x] + E^((3*x^2)/2)*y[x])),y[x],x]

 DSolve[Derivative[1][y][x] == (E^(3*x^2)*x*(3 + y[x])^3)/
    (81*(3*E^((3*x^2)/2) + 3*y[x] + E^((3*x^2)/2)*y[x])),y[x],x]

 DSolve[Derivative[1][y][x] == (1 + x*y[x])^3/x^5,y[x],x]

 DSolve[Derivative[1][y][x] == (x^2 - x^3 + 3*x^2*y[x] - 3*x*y[x]^2 +
      y[x]^3)/((-1 + x)*(1 + x)),y[x],x]

 DSolve[Derivative[1][y][x] == ((-1 + x)*y[x]*(E^(2*x) + E^x*x*y[x] +
    x^2*y[x]^2))/(E^(2*x)*x),y[x],x]

 DSolve[-y[x] + a^(2*n)*(1 + n)*y[x]^(1 + 2*n) + Derivative[2][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]

 DSolve[4*y[x]^2 - x^2*Derivative[1][y][x]*(x + Derivative[1][y][x]) + 
   x^4*Derivative[2][y][x] == 0,y[x],x]
```

To see the solutions in `v10.4` and compare, here link to actual report. [kamke_differential_equations](http://12000.org/my_notes/kamek/kamke_differential_equations.htm)

This is `v11` 64 bit on windows 7 64 bit. Same platform for `v10.4`

**Question is**: Why `v11` do not solve these `29` ODE's when it did in `v10.4` ?

Comment: I don't have time to track down the reason right now, and certainly not for all 29.  For the first one, the solution in V10.4.1 is an implicit solution in terms of `Solve[..]`.  If I paste this `Solve[]` command into V11, it runs for longer than I can wait.  Perhaps, it's a change in `Solve` that is the difference.

Comment: @Nasser: Excellent testing! This and a bunch of other postings makes you wonder what sort of test harness they are using to verify these purported upgrades! Some of the things I have seen are very annoying and I am not sure why they are considered an improvement. Some other CAS already performed better on DEQs and then to have this regression in ability is disheartening. Maybe MMA updates are getting like the Windows OS, you just skip every other one!

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for checking. Yes, all these ODE's are solved in 10.4 using implicit result. I expected at least same result from 11.

Comment: Indeed a trace shows an equivalent `Solve[]` command is tried inside the V11 `DSolve[]`.  I guess some "advance" in `Solve` causes it to try harder to solve the equation.

Comment: I enjoyed browsing your comparison website.  From your study, it seems Maple solves more ODEs, giving less verbose results and in a shorter amount of time than Mathematica.  Have I understood this correctly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The hangs in `DSolve` appear to be caused by a change in `Solve`, which attempts to use a wider variety of methods (based on those available in `Reduce`) for transcendental equations in *Mathematica* version 11.

This issue clearly needs to be fixed, but a temporary work around is to set the `Method` option for `Solve` as shown below.

```
In[1]:= SetOptions[Solve, Method -> "Restricted"];

In[2]:= DSolve[-((y[x]*f'[x])/f[x]) - f[x]*g'[x] - 
    a^n*f[x]^(1 - n)*y[x]^n*g'[x] + y'[x] == 0, y[x], x] // Head

Out[2]= Solve
```

The above `Method` setting is already used by `DSolve` internally in version 11 but, unfortunately, it does not help in the case of difficult implicit solutions returned by `DSolve`.

Thank you for posting these examples, and sorry for the confusion caused by the problem.